# The API data I want to show on screen in React Native is being called more than once

Tags: javascript, sql-server, react-native, fetch-api

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "CariId": 2,
  "CariBakiyeyeSadeceOnayliFaturalarYansisin": false,
  "DonemId": 1,
  "BasTarih": "01.01.2021",
  "BitTarih": "01.01.2023"
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};


useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.30:2828/CodesAndroid.svc/CariHesapListesiDetayli", requestOptions);
    const result = await response.text();
    const parsedResult=JSON.parse(result);
    setData(parsedResult);
  };

  fetchData();
}, []);
```

```
<View><FlatList
    data={data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View>
        <Text>{data}</Text>
      </View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item.CariId}
  /></View>
```

Comment: My DB datas calls a lot although I use  useEffect(() => { const fetchData = async () => { const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.30:2828/CodesAndroid.svc/CariHesapListesiDetayli", requestOptions); const result = await response.text(); const parsedResult=JSON.parse(result); setData(parsedResult); };

fetchData(); }, []);

Answer (score 1):

==> Maybe it will work.

```
import {useIsFocused} from "@react-navigation/native";

const isFocused = useIsFocused()

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [isFocused]);



const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.30:2828/CodesAndroid.svc/CariHesapListesiDetayli", requestOptions);
        const result = await response.text();
        const parsedResult=JSON.parse(result);
        setData(parsedResult);
      };
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly does not work #Ankit Vora